# Is it possible to have a drop-in file for templates?

Tags: systemd

I have a template file (namely `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service`) which has an `ExecStart` entry.

This entry is correct for all services started from that template, except for one. For that special one (say `systemd-nspawn@specialcontainer.service`) I would like to have a different `ExecStart`.

For non-template services, I would in that case use a drop-in. **Is there an equivalent for template-based service units?** I would need a way to inform `systemd` that this is *"a drop-in for the template service unit, when `%i` is `specialcontainer`"*

Answer (score 2):

Yep - this is possible.

You need to have an override `.d` folder for the exact service name you want to override - you can see this quite nicely if you do

```
sudo systemctl edit systemd-nspawn@specialcontainer.service
```

This will create a file (on my machine at least, running Ubuntu 16.04) at `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@specialcontainer.service.d/override.conf` with changes.

https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/915810 has a way more comprehensive answer - using the `getty` template systemd unit as an example.